# ASP.NET Update Panel not rendering in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, web-part, asp.net

I am currently developing a webpart that has implemented an ASP update panel:

**HTML:**

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="true" Interval="1000" ></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName="Tick" ControlID="Timer1" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName="ServerClick" ControlID="btnAdvanceStep2" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**The C# code for the Timer1_Tick:**

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
}
```

Alright, this works fine, it runs Timer1_Tick, fills TextBox1, but this does not get rendered inside of my webpart. What's going on? How can I solve this?

Comment: Just scrap it. It doesn't work with SharePoint 2013 because of differences in the postback mechanisms that are used by SharePoint and ASP.NET. Instead try to use some other method to load data async.

Comment: @Ilyas We tried creating a new blank solution on our sharepoint project, and inserting our update panel into this new project, into the new webpart (a blank one). It worked! Our guess is that some javascript is in some way, interfering with the update panel.

Comment: it worked for me as well, but was creating other issues and causing other out of the box SharePoint things to not work properly, and also causing some issues when in edit mode.